# How to target and set styles between styled components in React Native withTypescript

Tags: css, typescript, react-native, styled-components

I want to do like I always did in React with Styled Components.

```
import styled from "styled-components";

import {Wrapper as CardComponent} from '../../components/Card/style';

export const Wrapper = styled.div`
 ${CardComponent}{
 ...the styles
}
`
```

But this isn't working with React Native.

```
import styled from "styled-components/native";

import {Wrapper as CardComponent} from '../../components/Card/style';

export const Wrapper = styled.View`
 ${CardComponent}{
 ...the styles
}
`
```

There is any way to target and set rules between styled components in react native?

Comment: Can you show us the props for `CardComponent`?

Comment: const CardComponent = ({children}) => <Wrapper> {children} </Wrapper>

Comment: From the [docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components): >This is a web-specific API and you won't be able to use it in react-native.